QGIS - add OS NGD Tiles - API as a vector layer
I have been making good use of QGIS and found the help files able to get me through most problems, although now I am completely stuck at trying to get the "OS NGD API - Tiles" vector tiles layer loaded into QGIS.
QGIS is unable to connect to the service, suggesting it is a simple formatting error of the URL but I am none the wiser.
I have managed to add many other layer types such as the free "OS Vector Tile API" with a style url. It looks good but is low detail.
Has anyone had any success adding the NGD vector tiles layer and if so, how have you managed it?
I am trying to use this URL with the project key appended to it:
https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/ngd/ota/v1?key=
Ideally I'd be able to use this and a styles URL and configure with 27700 CRS but have not had any luck. I have managed to get the NGD URL to work via the OS Code Playground but not QGIS.

